# Books on quantum mechanics with intuition

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations

So, I know that there are a lot of questions about good books on quantum mechanics and I have read each one of them, and I go on and bought Griffiths' Introduction to Quantum Mechanics. But the fact is that it did not build me a very good intuition as it emphasized the computational part of it.

So, I want a book that emphasizes on both intuition and mathematical rigor in the same way.
I am thinking about the books of Dirac, Shankar, Zettili, Landau and  Claude Cohen-Tannoudji (with Frank Laboe).

So what are your opinions about them and which one strikes the balance on intuition and mathematical rigor?

If you know other books that emphasize on both, tell me.

Comment: It is my humble opinion that pretty much the only way to develop intuition in QM (if there even is such a thing) is by practicing the math.

Comment: Well,i do not think that it is the only way and certainly not the most complete way.Some books graphs and images and are a bit more talky than say Griffith's book,and that builds more intuition

Comment: Hi Landos Adam, resource recommendations question are restricted on Phys.SE, so I'm closing this as a _duplicate_ even if it ain't an exact duplicate.

Comment: @LandosAdam  I agree with you 100% that intuition is helpful (but only sometimes) and I personally find it difficult to **stop** trying to get an intuitive picture, even though it does hold up practicing the math and mostly leads me the down the wrong direction.

Comment: Intuition would not be good if it was not helpful.You can't go wrong with good intuition.If the intuition gets you wrong answers it means that you just got something wrong and need to revise your intuition

Comment: For intuition , you ought to read [Introduction to Quantum Physics by French & Taylor](http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Quantum-Physics-M-I-T-Introductory/dp/0393091066).

Comment: I heard good stuff about it.Will try it!

Comment: Have you tried reading Ballentine's book *Quantum Mechanics: A modern development* ?

Comment: @NiGGa is it for beginners?

Comment: @LandosAdam Not really, but I started QM with it gives you great insight and feel for the subject.

Answer (score 4):

The only book that I know can help build you intuition is "Lectures on Quantum Mechanics" by Weinberg.

Weinberg's book is used to give a course in Advanced QM. It should not be your first read on the subject. The book is quite enlightening because it sheds lights on details that most QM books jump over without explaining the intuition or at least the physics behind them.

Comment: This is not really the level of detail we look for in resource-recommendation questions. Please provide more information about the book's content and level.

Comment: Well,i will try to build intuition from the get-go.I want to know what happens from the starting point rather than just doing maths..

Comment: Do you have anything else in mind that is for beginners?

Comment: As far as my experience is concerned, you will always find QM shocking at the beginning. This you should know.

If you have time and you are not rushing into this, I suggest that you start with this book http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-EHEP002383.html and then you read Weinberg's.

Comment: I was thinking about Zettili.Does his book provide the nessesary intuition and mathematical rigor?

Comment: It is a good book and yes, it gives *necessary* intuition. Now, that is exactly why I stress on the fact that you back it up with Weinberg's great book! I have read many QM books, but in order to achieve what you want, in my opinion, it is a 2-phase adventure.

1) Zettili to get a flavour of what is what and a relatively good book (it also has solved problems in it that are very helpful)

2) Weinberg to put the cherry on the top.

Comment: will try them both